# Identifying elements in a list from sys.argv to do Reverse Polish Notation

Tags: python, linux, list, argv, postfix-notation

I am having issues parsing arguments entered on command line that become part of a list.
The following code correctly identifies whether an argument is either an operand or number, and thus makes the calculations correctly:

```
import operator
ops = { '+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.div }
import sys
print str(sys.argv)
array = sys.argv
total = 0
for i in range(1,len(array)):
    if array[i] == '+' or array[i] == '-' or array[i] == '*' or array[i] == '/':
        answer = ops[array[i]](float(array[i - 2]),float(array[i - 1]))
        total += answer
print total
```

So `$ 1 1 + 1 0 -` outputs `3`

However the above logic is incorrect for Reverse Polish Notation. The below logic is better (forgive any indentation errors), but for some reason now the code doesn't identify whether the arguments are operands or numbers:

```
import operator
ops = { '+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.div }
import sys
print str(sys.argv)
array = sys.argv
i = 1
my_stack = []
while i < len(array):
#    if array[i] == float(array[i]) or array[i] == int(array[i]):

     if array[i] != '+' or array[i] != '-' or array[i] != '*' or array[i] != '/':
        my_stack.insert(0, array[i])
     else:
        answer = ops[array[i]](float(my_stack[1]),float(my_stack[0]))
        my_stack.pop(1)
        my_stack.pop(0)        
        my_stack.insert(0, answer)
     i = i + 1
print my_stack[0]
```

I've tried positively identifying if elements are numbers (floats or integers), and negatively identifying if elements are not operands, but neither approach is working. Either the command line doesn't recognize that element is not an operand, or doesn't recognize that element is float or integer.
Any thoughts on how to identify if elements of list are numbers or operands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine whether a value is an operator by checking whether it exists as a key in your `ops` dictionary:

```
import operator

ops = { '+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.div }

if array[i] in ops:
    # it's an operator
else:
    # it's an operand... maybe
```

This has the advantage that you can easily support new operators just by adding them to your `ops` dictionary, e.g. modulo:

```
ops = { '%': operator.mod, '+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, ...}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a better way to go about it in the future.

Comment: @NatG: This is a better way to go about it now and in the future. Syntactically this is much nicer than using multiple conditions in an if statement. It is less error prone, more maintainable and easily extensible.

Answer (score 1):

You have not followed DeMorgan's Law correctly. The second example must use "and" between the "!=" parts.

```
 if array[i] != '+' and array[i] != '-' and array[i] != '*' and array[i] != '/':
```